# Create list of two lists of zeros

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to create a list of two lists of zeros for 20 times, like this:

```
[[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0],[0][0]]
```

I tried this:

```
output = []
for j in range(20) :
    output.append([0])
```

I which it gives me:

```
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
```

But this is not what I want :(

Any help, please?

Comment: Does doing `output.append([0, 0])` do what you want? Your first example isn't valid code, as `[0][0]` isn't valid syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a list like `[[0][0], [0][0]]` is not a valid syntax in Python, but you can have something like this: `[[0, 0]]` by doing the following.

```
zeros_list = [[0, 0] for _ in range(20)]
```

**output**

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Or you can have something like this `[[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]]`, which would be a list of lists of lists containing zeros by doing:

```
zeros_list = [[[0], [0]] for _ in range(20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
result = [[0, 0]] * 20
print (result)
#[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

result = [[[0], [0]]] * 20
print (result)
#[[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]]
```